How to detect a template function could impose a less strict concept
This is a kind of follow-up question to How to detect a template function should impose a more strict concept.
I have some code that looks like this:
#include <iterator>

template<std::random_access_iterator Iter>
auto compare(Iter i1, Iter i2)
{
    return i1 < i2;
}

I then realise I can replace less than with not equal to:
template<std::random_access_iterator Iter>
auto compare(Iter i1, Iter i2)
{
    return i1 != i2;
}

Now the concept constrain can be downgraded to forward_iterator. Is there a way to help me detect this, apart from a careful code review?

These aren't equivalent, and there's no tool that can know your actual intent without explaining it (which pretty much comes down to writing the code)

@rubenvb I know they are not equivalent. No tool can know my intent, yet compiler can emit a warning for if (a = b), because I likely meant if (a == b), even though assignment could be there on purpose.

what the concept and what the implementation require is not necessarily identical. Your compare can be totally fine as it is, if that is what you want

Compare functions are commonly required to respect strict weak ordering, and your second one does not. Out of curiosity: what do you need it for ?

What is the strict aliasing rule?

@wohlstad What I was working on boils down to a for loop: for (; a < b;) vs for(; a != b;), where a and b are iterators. The compare function I posted was just a proxy for the comparison in the loop. Perhaps it would be less confusing if I posted the loop as an example.

@wohlstad not all compare function are required to implement a strict weak ordering. Those used for sorting yes, but there others

@463035818_is_not_an_ai sure. But I usually encountered them in sort-like context. Anyway as I wrote I was just curios about the OP use case.

@KrzysiekKarbowiak  not really possible using the compiler only. Have you considered clang-tidy, with possibly customized check? Also, the question is: do you mean really
a. detecting if constraint on the param can be relaxed (I assume that's the case) or b. enforcing specific comparison of iterators. The latter is surely possible, the former - maybe, but I'm not sure.
